# Getting string from variable

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

```
DECLARE @dbfilepath nvarchar(128)
SET @dbfilepath = 'C:\SqlDataFiles\Cache.mdf'
GO

USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [Cache] ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'Cache', FILENAME = @dbfilepath, SIZE = 3072KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
GO
```

**Why doesn't this work?**

It gives:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near '@dbfilepath'.

Comment: You cannot use a variable inside a `CREATE DATABASE` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exec it;

```
USE [master]
GO
DECLARE @dbfilepath nvarchar(128) = 'C:\MSSQL\Cache.mdf'
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'CREATE DATABASE [Cache] ON PRIMARY (NAME = N''Cache'', FILENAME = ''' + @dbfilepath + ''', SIZE = 3072KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )'
EXEC(@SQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @dbfilepath nvarchar(128);
SET @dbfilepath = 'C:\\SqlDataFiles\\Cache.mdf';
PRINT @dbfilepath;
```

To use  @dbfilepath in the Create Database statement, dynamic sql needs to be used.

Comment: It is printing the same path as mentioned.

Comment: @SQL. Yes. But now the error won't come, which was mentioned in the question.